# Why does the DataStateBehavior not update initially?

Tags: wpf, visualstatemanager

I have bound a `ListBox` to my ViewModel including the `ListBox.SelectedItem`. I want to change a visual state depending on if there is one selected or not, but The following doesn't update the state initially, so it stays in the wrong state:

```
<DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedCamera}" Value="{x:Null}" TrueState="CameraSettingsUnselected" FalseState="CameraSettingsSelected"/>
```

Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that the binding initially evaluates to `null` and thus doesn't fire the change notification required for the evaluation and state change.

I've fixed it with the following subclass:

```
public class FixedDataStateBehavior: DataStateBehavior
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, routedEventArgs) =>
            {
                var bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, BindingProperty);
                SetCurrentValue(BindingProperty,new object());
                bindingExpression.UpdateTarget();
            };
    }
}
```

and used it like this:

```
<FixedDataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding SelectedCamera}" Value="{x:Null}" TrueState="CameraSettingsUnselected" FalseState="CameraSettingsSelected"/>
```

Comment: You asked this question 4 minutes ago and answered yourself 4 minutes ago?! What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works, but I ended up creating a more generic Behavior class that would simply work with all bindings without needing to specify them individually.

```
public class RefreshDataContextBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dc = this.AssociatedObject.DataContext;
        this.AssociatedObject.DataContext = null;
        this.AssociatedObject.DataContext = dc;
    }
}
```

Then simply insert it into the XAML like so on the object which has the DataContext:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:RefreshDataContextBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Be careful with OnDetaching(). It doesn't always fire when the behavior is being destroyed. If you add a this.AssociatedObject.UnLoaded event handler and unsubscribe everything there, you should be safe.